# How to make dynamic content-editable table using angular JS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, html-table

**Caveat**: I've just started with client side scripting and Angular JS is the first thing I'm learning and now I feel I should've started with javascript.
**PS**: I don't wanna use any third party libraries. I wanna learn to code.

Anyway,I have dynamic table which I want to make editable using content-editable=true attribute of HTML.

**Problem**: How to I get the edited data? whenever I click on submit and pass the this object to the check() function. I doesn't contain edited values. is there a possible way to pass only edited value if it's dirty. It has pagination so If g to the next page the edited values are gone. I know I've give unique Id to every td element with $Index concatenated to it. But I don't know how should I proceed.

Any help or guidance will be appreciated. Controllers and others are defined in my route.

```
<div>
<form ng-submit="check(this)">
    <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="data in currentItems">
                <td contenteditable="true >{{data.EmpNo}}</td>
                <td contenteditable="true">{{data.isActive}}</td>
                <td contenteditable="true">{{data.balance}}</td>
                <td contenteditable="true">{{data.age}}</td>
                <td contenteditable="true">{{data.eyeColor}}</td>
                <td contenteditable="true">{{data.fname}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <td>
                <div class="pagination pull-right">
                    <li ng-class="{'disabled': previousPage}">
                        <a ng-click="previousPage()" >Previous</a>
                    </li>   
                    <li ng-repeat="page in pageLengthArray track by $index">
                        <a ng-click="pagination($index)">{{$index+1}} </a>
                    </li>
                    <li  disabled="disabled">
                        <a ng-click="nextPage()" ng-class="{'disabled':nextPage}>Next </a>
                    </li>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

```
     $scope.currentPage=0;
     $scope.pageSize=10;
     $scope.currentItems;
     $scope.tableData;
   $http.get('../json/generated.json').then(function(response){
      $scope.tableData=response.data;
      $scope.pageLength=Math.ceil($scope.tableData.length/$scope.pageSize);
           $scope.currentItems=$scope.tableData.slice($scope.currentPage,$scope.pageSize);
      $scope.pageLengthArray= new Array($scope.pageLength);
    });

        $scope.pagination=function(currentPage){   $scope.currentItems=$scope.tableData.slice($scope.pageSize*currentPage,$scope.pageSize*currentPage+$scope.pageSize);
          $scope.currentPage=currentPage;
        }   
        $scope.nextPage=function nextPage(argument) {
              $scope.currentPage++;  $scope.currentItems=$scope.tableData.slice(($scope.pageSize*$scope.currentPage),($scope.pageSize*($scope.currentPage)+$scope.pageSize));
            }
        $scope.previousPage=function previousPage(argument) {
          $scope.currentPage--;
          $scope.currentItems=$scope.tableData.slice(($scope.pageSize*$scope.currentPage),($scope.pageSize*($scope.currentPage)+$scope.pageSize));
        }
```

Comment: so you want your `check` function to only receive the objects that have been edited?

Comment: you can use `$dirty` to check which data is changed.

Comment: Yes @SuperVeetz but I'll be fine as long as I can get the edited values along with some key that states they've been edited so from the whole object I can just take the edited fields and update that in the database. Thank you

Comment: To define runtime id to `td` you do something like this `<td contenteditable="true" id="empno_{{$index}}">`, this way you'll get different id for all. something like `<td contenteditable="true" id="empno_0">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the usual case, you can not get a change model for `contenteditabe` because to change the model used `ngModel`.

But we can create a directive that we have updated the value of the model.

Live example on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/aao4fwdh/).

```js
angular.module('ExampleApp', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', function($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.data = {
      EmpNo: "123"
    };
  })
  .directive('contenteditable', function($timeout) {
    return {
      restrict: "A",
      priority: 1000,
      scope: {
        ngModel: "="
      },
      link: function(scope, element) {
        element.html(scope.ngModel);
        element.on('focus blur keyup paste input', function() {
          scope.ngModel = element.text();
          scope.$apply();
          return element;
        });
      }
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="ExampleApp">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">

    <table>
      <tr>
        <td ng-model="data.EmpNo" contenteditable="true"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <pre>{{data|json}}</pre>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, that was a great solution, However, I was hoping if you can answer me a few question for a better understanding of my concepts
1) why are we prioritising the directive when my post-link function doesn't do any DOM Manipulation, that too, 1000  neither I want it to run before a directive(I don't know)?
2) why do we return the element at last and why element.html(scope.ngModel)?

Comment: another thing is I recalculate currentItems every time I click to go the next page(naive logic). Now, I edit something, the currentItems gets updated because of the ng-model.However, since I recalculate currentItems every time I click when I go to the next page and come back I shouldn't see updated value because the previously calculated currentItems is gone but somehow, unnaturally I do. I don't get this concept.How does this happen? if the currentItems had been same all the time I get it, but I'm recalculating it shouldn't show me updated values. Please bear with my lack of understanding.

Comment: You can remove a priority in 1000 at the directive, it will not change anything. `element.html(scope.ngModel)` you need to set the initial value in the element. Show in question source code of `nextPage` function.

Comment: The value of variable `currentItems` is obtained by copying the value of the variable `tableData`. When you change a value in `currentItems`  variable element and also changes in the value of the variable `tableData`. Therefore, when you change the page and returns to the previous page, the value is stored in element.

Comment: Oh thank you @Stepan_Kasyanenko for your time and patience.

Answer (score 0):

I would store any object that gets modified in a seperate array using the `ng-keyup` directive. When the form is submitted, you will have an array of only elements which have been modified. You may have some UX issues if your pagination is done by server as when you change page and come back, it will show your old data, but hopefully this helps.

```
$scope.check = function () {
    // check modifiedItems
    console.log(modifiedItems);
};

// store modified objects in a seperate array
var modifiedItems = [];

$scope.modifyItem = function (data) {

    // check if data has already been modified and splice it first
    for(var i = 0, j = modifiedItems.length; i < j; i++) {
        var currentItem = modifiedItems[i];

        if (currentItem.id === data.id) {
            modifiedItems.splice(i, 1);
            break;
        }
    }

    // add to modified
    modifiedItems.push(data);
    console.log('modifiedItems: ', modifiedItems);
};
```

HTML

```
<form ng-submit="check()">
    <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="data in currentItems">
                <td ng-repeat="(key, value) in data" contenteditable="true"
                    ng-keyup="modifyItem(data)">
                    {{data[key]}}
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: I appreciate your time and knowledge, it was a pretty good makeshift @SuperVeetz However, as pointed, I was facing pagination issues so I thought the better way would be to go with the solution provided by ^StepanKasyanenko though tricky at first but helps one with a better understanding of the concept.